# javascript click div to add border only if it is a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, border, addition

How could I add a border to a div with javascript/jquery when clicked? I need one div with class of column in each row to have the border when a user selects/clicks it. but it needs to be only one column div per row selectable at a time, so only one div with class column can be 'highlighted' with a border at a time. but each row will have on div with a border. hope this makes sense. Basically the html is structured like so...

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="column"></div>
 <div class="column"></div>
 <div class="column"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="column"></div>
 <div class="column"></div>
 <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

I am terrible at js and jquery, obviously.
Thanks all, in advance.

Comment: [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/6Fc2M/2/)?

Comment: yes sir! thanks. I sure hope web is your job!

Answer (score 1):

Add a `click` handler to each `column`, add a class to the one clicked, and remove that class from all siblings:

```
$('.column').on('click', function() {
   $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight'); 
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Fc2M/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this one,.

`$('.column').click(function(){
      $('.column').each(function(){
           $(this).removeClass('highlight');
         });
     $(this).addClass('hightlight');
})`

Comment: This work fantastically, but is there a way to have each row allow one div to be selected without removing the class from the row above? I have three rows each need one div .highlighted per each row.

Comment: I think if i add a specific class to each ros ie. row1 row2 that will work. Thanks again Maneesh Singh, You. Are. Good.